# Updating my Android app doesn't work, makes the app crash. Completely reinstall works. Seems to be common. Is there a solution?

Tags: android, version-control, version

Whenever I build a new version of my Android app and install it, it doesn't really make a completely new installation (uninstall and reinstall) it kind of patches the previous version I made. When I launch the app it just crashes.

Then I manually completely uninstall my app and then reinstall it from zero. In this case it works like a charm. The problem is that I'm worried about how will this affect the distribution of my app and automatic updates. Is there a solution?

What I'm doing is this: I have my app, let's say v 3.1, I build the v 3.2 then copy the apk into my phone and execute it. It updates... Then, the app crashes on start. Then if I completely uninstall the app and then run the apk file of that very same version v 3.2 it works fine. I don't know why that happens

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. What I'm doing is this:

I have my app, let's say v 3.1, I build the v 3.2 then copy the apk into my phone and execute it. It updates... Then, the app crashes on start.

Then if I completely uninstall the app and then run the apk file of that very same version v 3.2 it works fine. I don't know why that happens

Answer (score 0):

As far as crash is concerned you need to print the log , to know why it is exactly crashing, it could be due to some variable on your launcher screen which gets NPE may be because it is getting cleared. Since the package name of application is same it will obviously work in similar manner as you mentioned. Crash must not be due to reinstall of application.Till you find out the reason for crash it will not be possible to tell that exactly how it is going to affect your application.But it is never ok to distribute app which is crashing in any manner.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. What I find weird is that if I install the app from zero (the new version) it doesn't crash or present any errors. Are you sure then that it might be a problem that I will be able to fix (because that means it would be my fault)? Or this is just another weird Android behaviour or bug?

Comment: I don't think this is android behaviour, you app does not crash on fisr instance because the value may be getting initialized on first instance but getting cleared on and you have not handled it. for example it could be due to some value getting null,ie it is setting on first instance but getting cleared later on,may be some shared preference value or some string on your splash screen ,it is difficult to tell without seeing the code, and we cannot get the exact reason till you post the response log.